# ModuleNotFoundError with Azure function Apps using Python

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have exactly the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546175/modulenotfounderror-with-azure-function-apps-using-python) some time ago.

I tried the recommended solutions: `pip install azure`

But no luck!

This is the code I'm following in the basic tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python):

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hellod {name}!")

    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.functions'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to run `pip install azure-functions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, this was working fine.
Make sure you are performing Azure functions inside a virtual environment.

A virtual environment is automatically created when we select a python interpreter while creating the Azure functions.

[image]

Alternatively, you can refer below commands to create a virtual environment.

| Description | Command |
| --- | --- |
| Install Virtual Environment | pip3 install virtualenv |
| Create Virtual Environment | Python3 -m venv .venv |
| Activate Virtual Environment | .venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 |

After creating a virtual environment then try installing azure functions using pip

```
pip install azure-functions
```

Also, make sure that the installed packages have been included in the `requirements.txt` file

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

**REFERENCES:** [Troubleshoot ModuleNotFoundError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#troubleshoot-modulenotfounderror)

Comment: Thank you, pip install azure-functions solved the problem, now I'm stuck on nothing happening upon running __init__.py so I'll open another question.